# can't select unique records based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have an Excel sheet `report` formatted like this:

```
+----------+--------+-------------+
|   file   | column | columnIndex |
+----------+--------+-------------+
| abc.xlsx | test   |          14 |
| def.xlsx | test   |          55 |
| abc.xlsx | xyz    |          19 |
| def.xlsx | xyz    |          19 |
+----------+--------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to query it with ADODB so that I can get the unique pairs of `column` and `columnIndex` values where `column` is not blank.

I have tried various queries but each one has given me an error.

```
SELECT [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
from [report$] group by [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
having [report$].column<>''
ORDER BY columnIndex
```

gives this error:

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

This query:

```
select [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
from [report$] group by [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
where [report$].column<>'' 
order by columnIndex
```

gives this error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[report$].columnIndex where [report$].column<>'''.
```

This query:

```
select distinct [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
from [report$] 
where [report$].column<>'' 
order by columnIndex
```

gives this error:

```
ORDER BY clause (columnIndex) conflicts with DISTINCT.
```

How can I write this query to get the unique values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `WHERE` goes before `GROUP BY`
- `<>` is an equivalent to `!=` so you should pass value to compare your `[report$].column` with.
- Probably the reason for `No value given for one or more required parameters.` is a misspelled field name.

For example :

```
WHERE [report$].column <> '' 
GROUP BY [report$].column,[report$].columnIndex 
ORDER BY [report$].columnIndex
```

Comment: With this query, I'm still getting the `No value given for one or more required parameters` error.

Comment: Never mind.  The problem was that the column `columnIndex` was actually named `column index`, so it wasn't being recognized in the query.  This works now.